# Java cannot find imports in Class URLConnection.java

Tags: java, android-studio, class, import

I am using Android Studio on a Mac. While working with the Class **URLConnection.java** I found out, that certain classes in **URLConnection.java** don't import correctly:
[image]

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Why is it an issue?

Comment: @shmosel Because certain methods can't be resolved.

Comment: For more help post the full error, and more details about your JDK/JVM. It sounds like your JDK is broken, or if this is a custom class, then don't use `sun` packages, especially if this application is for use on Android or across multiple platforms with various java versions? See here for more information: https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/faq-sun-packages.html "A Java program that directly calls into sun.* packages is not guaranteed to work on all Java-compatible platforms. In fact, such a program is not guaranteed to work even in future versions on the same platform."

Answer (score 1):

There are no `sun.*` packages on the Android platform.

So if you are building for Android, the solution is to **change the code** so that it doesn't depend on those packages.

For the record, it was always a bad idea to use `sun.*` packages, even on Oracle Java.  As the [Oracle Java documentation](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/faq-sun-packages.html) states:

> "A Java program that directly calls into sun.* packages is not guaranteed to work on all Java-compatible platforms. In fact, such a program is not guaranteed to work even in future versions on the same platform."

Judging from the names of the packages, you are only using them to get some constant definitions.  (HTTP response codes?)  The constants are most likely defined in another class on the Android platform.  But your question doesn't explain the reasons for those imports, so I can't give specific suggestions.

---

Notes:

1. If you are trying to recompile the standard Java SE `URLConnection` class for Android, my advice is: Don't.

   Android already has that class, so the standard Java SE version is not needed.  If you really need to modify the class (on Android) for some reason, start from the Android source code.  It shouldn't have those `sun.*` dependencies.
2. If you are trying to use Android Studio to develop non-Android Java, it would probably be simpler to use an IDE that is designed for that purpose.  But if you must ... make sure that you tell Android Studio to compile your code against the Java SE libraries.